# AngularUI Accordion toggle on scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularUI Bootstrap accordion and I need it to be open depending on data, coming from a $http request, here's my markup:

```
<div data-accordion>
    <div data-accordion-group data-heading="Group 1" is-open="!$parent.toggle">
        <!-- random content -->          
    </div>
    <div data-accordion-group data-heading="Group 2" is-open="$parent.toggle">
        <!-- random content --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's an example of the data coming in:

```
randomService.getdata(id).then(function(response) {
    randomService.toggle = response.data;
    $scope.toggle = randomService.toggle;
});
```

The problem with this setup is that if I click the header to open/close, the variable gets toggled as well(I want to avoid that). It can be avoided by changing the `is-open` to `!( !!($parent.toggle)` and `!!($parent.toggle)`, respectively.

However the problem remains: When $scope.toggle is false the proper accordion is open, when it's true both accordions are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to use two scope variables open1 and open2, so you can always set the right one to true when the data comes in, no matter what state they are in. This should also work if the accordion has the attribute close-others set to true.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using a similar approach(had to shuffle my data a bit).